# What is the best way to fix "IFs hell"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

I have a Deal class, that has several states : New, Bought, Finished, trend and crossing properties. Deal instance can change trend and crossing any time - depends of market condition.

Depend of current "trend", "crossing" and maybe other conditions  deal can be processed in different ways

I tried Strategy and Chain of Responsibility patterns but my knowledge and experience isn't enough to do it correctly. And I'm not sure that made the right decision.

Now it works but it's a hell of ifs

```
async def check_deal(deal):

    if deal.is_new():
        if deal.current_trend == UP_TREND and CROSSED_TOP_GREEN in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_TOP_GREEN)

        if deal.current_trend == FLAT_TREND and CROSSED_BOTTOM_ORANGE in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_BOTTOM_ORANGE)

        if deal.current_trend == DOWN_TREND and CROSSED_BOTTOM in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_BOTTOM)

    if deal.is_bought() and not deal.candle_has_order:
        if deal.current_trend == UP_TREND and CROSSED_BOTTOM_GREEN in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_BOTTOM_GREEN)
        else:
            return await deal.update_deal()

        if deal.current_trend == DOWN_TREND and CROSSED_BOTTOM in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_BOTTOM)
        else:
            return await deal.update_deal()

    else:
        return await deal.update_deal()

    if deal.is_profitable() and len(deal.orders) == 1 :
        if deal.current_trend == UP_TREND  and CROSSED_TOP in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.trailing_enable(CROSSED_TOP)

        if deal.current_trend == FLAT_TREND and CROSSED_TOP_GREEN in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.trailing_enable(CROSSED_TOP_GREEN)

        if deal.current_trend == DOWN_TREND and CROSSED_BASIS in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.trailing_enable(CROSSED_BASIS)

    if deal.is_profitable() and len(deal.orders) > 1:
        if deal.current_trend == UP_TREND and CROSSED_BASIS in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.trailing_enable(CROSSED_BASIS)

        if deal.current_trend == DOWN_TREND and  CROSSED_BOTTOM_GREEN in deal.crossing:
            return await deal.trailing_enable(CROSSED_BOTTOM_GREEN)
```

Rules

current crossing is a variable and can be different any time
current trend is a variable and can be different any time

We start deal in one of the cases:

1. Deal.is_new()  (deal isn't saved to datatabase ) and current trend is UP and current crossing is in deal.crossing
2. Deal.is_new() and current trend is FLAT and current crossing is in deal.crossing
3. Deal.is_new() and current trend is DOWN and current crossing is in deal.crossing

We add funds to current deal  in one of the cases:

1. Deal.is_bought() (deal is in database) and current trend is UP and current crossing is in deal.crossing
2. Deal.is_bought() (deal is in database) and current trend is DOWN and current crossing is in deal.crossing

We take profit on deal  in one of the cases:

1. Deal is profitable and deal has only 1 order  and current trend is UP and current crossing is in deal.crossing
2. Deal is profitable and deal has only 1 order  and current trend is FLAT and current crossing is in deal.crossing
3. Deal is profitable and deal has only 1 order  and current trend is DOWN  and current crossing is in deal.crossing
4. Deal is profitable and deal has more than 1 order  and current trend is UP and current crossing is in deal.crossing
5. Deal is profitable and deal has more than 1 order  and current trend is FLAT and current crossing is in deal.crossing
6. Deal is profitable and deal has more than 1 order  and current trend is DOWN and current crossing is in deal.crossing

We just update deal if deal.is_bought() and any others conditions aren't reached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is: *when a **condition** is met, an **action** needs to be performed*.

You can define an *interface* (you can use a simple base class or abstract base class) to capture this. Then add classes that *implement* this interface (inherit from the base class) for the various *if's* -> *action*.

Here's an example:

```
class Rule:

    def isMetBy(self, deal):
        pass

    def execute(self, deal):
        pass

class Rule1(Rule):

    def isMetBy(self, deal):
        return deal.current_trend == FLAT_TREND and CROSSED_BOTTOM_ORANGE in deal.crossing

    async def execute(self, deal):
        return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_BOTTOM_ORANGE)

class Rule2(Rule):

    def isMetBy(self, deal):
        return deal.current_trend == DOWN_TREND and CROSSED_BOTTOM in deal.crossing

    async def execute(self, deal):
        return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_BOTTOM)

rules = [Rule1(), Rule2()]

async def check_deal(deal):

    for rule in rules:
        if(rule.isMetBy(deal)):
            return await rule.execute(deal)
```

Each rule captures an if statement is your code. This way you can define as many rules as you need. Adding new ones is simply a matter of adding another class. If you can you will name your rules with good names, so this will add the benefit or *naming* your rules. I used Rule1 and Rule2 because I don't know what your rules mean. For example you can have something like (I just made this up for illustrational purpose) ***EnableTrailingForProfitableDealsRule***.

In your case you have one *if* with multiple *subif's* inside. You can decouple them to different classes or you can use the [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to create a ***rule*** with ***subrules***.

Here's an example:

```
class CompositeRule(Rule):
    subRules = []

    def __init(self):
        self.subRules = [Rule1(), Rule2()]

    def isMetBy(self, deal):

        if deal.is_profitable() and len(deal.orders) == 1 :
            for rule in self.subRules:
                if(rule.isMetBy(deal)):
                    return true;

        return false

    async def execute(self, deal);

        for rule in self.subRules:
            if(rule.isMetBy(deal)):
                return await rule.execute(deal)
```

`CompositeRules` can make the code easier or harder to understand. If your code get's harder to unerstand with `CompositeRules`, you can use simple rules instead. Many of these simple rules will have the same if statatement in them but that's usually not a problem.

Here's the `CompositeRule` broken down to two simple rules:

```
class Rule1(Rule):

    def isMetBy(self, deal):
        return if deal.is_profitable() and len(deal.orders) == 1 and deal.current_trend == UP_TREND  and CROSSED_TOP in deal.crossing

    async def execute(self, deal):
        return await deal.trailing_enable(CROSSED_TOP)

class Rule2(Rule):

    def isMetBy(self, deal):
        return if deal.is_profitable() and len(deal.orders) == 1 and  deal.current_trend == FLAT_TREND and CROSSED_TOP_GREEN in deal.crossing:

    async def execute(self, deal):
        return await deal.trailing_enable(CROSSED_TOP_GREEN)
```

You can experiment and choose the best approach that works for you.

Comment: that's what i'm looking for! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One cause of the complexity in your code is that your are handling *objects* in a *procedural* manner: `check_deal` is inspecting the deal's attributes and making decisions based on them, then calling the deal's methods.  This logic belongs in the  `Deal` class, say in a `Deal.check` method.

Moving the logic into the `Deal` class doesn't make it any less complex, but it opens the way to different design choices.

For example, rather than checking whether a `Deal` is new or bought or finished in blocks of conditional code you could have `NewDeal`, `BoughtDeal` and `FinishedDeal` subclasses whose `check` methods are only concerned with the decisions that affect these particular types.

If subclassing on type doesn't make sense in your application the strategy pattern could be another way to approach this - one `Deal` class but provide different check strategies based on deal type.

Another approach might be to model the events in a `Deal`'s lifecycle as a state machine.   Create `State` classes that represent each stage in the lifecycle, and which know the appropriate actions to take, and how to decide what the next state should be (chain of responsibility could be useful here).  This might need careful modelling  to prevent excessive coupling between `Deal` and `State`.

In short, try to structure your business logic so that you have classes which don't have to make decisions: they just do the right thing, or at least do the right thing with the minimal quantity of conditional code.

Answer (score 0):

> Now it works but it's a hell of ifs.

Your `if`-logic is flawed - you have unreachable code:

```
if deal.is_bought() and not deal.candle_has_order:
    if deal.current_trend == UP_TREND and CROSSED_BOTTOM_GREEN in deal.crossing:
        return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_BOTTOM_GREEN)
    else:
        return await deal.update_deal()

    # Neither of the following will EVER happen, you already 
    # left the function with the _else_ from above:
    if deal.current_trend == DOWN_TREND and CROSSED_BOTTOM in deal.crossing:
        return await deal.create_order(CROSSED_BOTTOM)
    else:
        return await deal.update_deal()
```

> I tried Strategy and Chain of Responsibility patterns but my knowledge
>   and experience isn't enough to do it correctly. And I'm not sure that
>   made the right decision.

Without knowledge of what your *rules* are we are kindof unable to help here. If you put all rules down, it might become *too broad* to be solved here.

Comment: Thank, missed that if. I added rules to the post

Answer (score 0):

If you use "elif" you make your computers job little easier becouse then it checks first "if" and if it is true it ignores all the "elif" and "else" that are connected to the that "if" but if you use "if" on every condition (like you do) your computer will go thru every "if" statement and check it. I hope this makes sense.